# Delete button in UIViewController which is showing the detail of a cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have an iPhone app that has a tableview which contains cells that when touched show a detail of that object. I would like to add a Delete button to the bottom of the detail view. When the user presses it the object which is represented by the cell should be removed and the app should return to the TableView.

In terms of best practices, which is the ideal way to accomplish this?

Comment: Where are you storing your data that the TableView and the detailview uses? You'd normally just delete that data or flag it as deleted and then dismiss the view, going back to your tableview.

Comment: Sounds good. But how do I generate the button in the first place? Programmatically or through Interface Builder? A snippet of code would be cool :)

Comment: I think there is nothing to serious thing about this, if you successfully delete the particular details after that on backing your tableview you just use  the                                    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated                                   {
                                                             [super viewWillAppear:animated];
                                                             [self.tableView reloadData];                                            }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few ways in which you can signal the deletion. One of them is delegates. You can define your delegate like this,

```
@protocol DetailViewControllerDelegate
- (void)shouldDeleteDetailObject:(id)object
@end
```

And then your table view controller subclass adopt the protocol and implement the method like,

```
- (void)shouldDeleteDetailObject:(id)object {
    [self.objectsArray removeObject:object];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

And then you message `[self.tableView reloadData];` in `viewWillAppear:` as sandy has indicated.

Your button action will be implemented as,

```
- (IBAction)deleteObject {
    if ( self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(shouldDeleteDetailObject:)] ) {
        [self.delegate shouldDeleteDetailObject:self.detailObject];
    }
}
```

And delegate should be an `assign`ed property.

You can also look at notifications but this is a better route for this situation.

Comment: @Eric Brotto Did this help? Do you need further assistance on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing serious about this, if you successfully delete the particular details after that on backing on previous view (tableview) you just use this

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];  
}
```